# r plotting multiple series and custom x axis labels

Tags: r, plot

I have data as below. I want to plot series y1 and y2 in different color lines and x axis labels should be values from variable x1. I am getting an error :(

```
x1=c("a","b","c")
y1=c(1,2,0)
y2=c(4,5,2)
plot(y1,xaxt='n',type="l")
axis(side = 1, at = x1,labels = T)

NAs introduced by coercionError in axis(side = 1, at = x1, labels = T) : no locations are finite
```

i would prefer if first 2 x axis labels come from x1 and third one is M. Something like `c(x[1:2],"M")`...how could I put custom labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eidt:

```
plot(1:3, y1, xaxt='n', type="l", ylim=range(c(y1, y2)))
points(1:3, y2, type = "l", col = "blue")
axis(side = 1, at = 1:3, labels = c(x1[1:2],"M"))
text(1:3, y1, y1)
text(1:3, y2, y2)
```

#

Is this what you are after?

```
   plot(y1, xaxt='n', type="l")
   axis(side = 1, at = 1:3, labels = c(x1[1:2],"M"))
```

I think you have to specify values `at` where your `labels` should go. Above works.

Comment: close..1).i would like to print series y2 also and in a different color line (say blue). 2)is there a way to rotate x axis labels by 90 degrees and 3) to display actual values of y1 data points (1,2,0) and y2(4,5,2)?

Comment: I've edited the answer for 1) and 3). I might try the 2) some other time.